# customview occupying the entire screen in the listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Android 2.3.3

I have a listview and i am populating a customview in it.

CustomView - ListView Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="2dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView_addcontact"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/addcontactsmall2"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_addcontact_contactname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview_addcontact_phonenumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chbk_addcontact"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView XML :::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtViewContactsHeader"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:text="Your Contacts (Phone + SIM)"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" />


     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/lv_addcontact"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

    </ListView>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btn_addcontact_add"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="ADD CONTACTS" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btn_addcontact_cancel"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="CANCEL" />

     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtViewNavigation"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="Navigation"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center" />

     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the application, the customview is getting populated with all the values that i need, but each customview is occupying the entire screen (space available for the listview). when i scroll down, i can see other rows.

Code - getView()

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // View MyView = convertView;

            ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {

                // Inflate the layout
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = li.inflate(
                        R.layout.activity_listview_addcontact_item, null);

                contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder();

                contactViewHolder.imgContact = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgView_addcontact);
                contactViewHolder.txtViewContactName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtView_addcontact_contactname);
                contactViewHolder.txtViewPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtview_addcontact_phonenumber);
                contactViewHolder.chbkAddContact = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chbk_addcontact);

                convertView.setTag(contactViewHolder);
            } else {
                contactViewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                cur.moveToPosition(position);

/*
                // Add The Image!!!
                String image = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

                if (image != null) {
                    contactViewHolder.imgContact.setImageURI(Uri.parse(image));
                } else {
                    contactViewHolder.imgContact
                            .setImageResource(R.drawable.addcontactsmall2);
                }
*/

                // Add Contact Name //

                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (name != null)
                    contactViewHolder.txtViewContactName.setText(name);
                else
                    contactViewHolder.txtViewContactName.setText("Unknown");


                // Add Phone Number //

                String phoneNumber = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                if (phoneNumber != null)
                    contactViewHolder.txtViewPhoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                else
                    contactViewHolder.txtViewPhoneNumber.setText("Unknown");

                //System.out.println(image + "   " + name + "   " + phoneNumber);

            //}

            return convertView;
        }

        public class ContactViewHolder {
            ImageView imgContact;
            TextView txtViewContactName;
            TextView txtViewPhoneNumber;
            CheckBox chbkAddContact;
        }
```

ScreenShot - If it can help

[image]

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me as incorrect in these layouts. Perhaps you can provide the code for your GetView() method (or wherever you are creating the custom view to be given to the ListView).

Comment: @BrettDuncavage I have added the getView() code. Please look into it.

Comment: @JoxTraex I have added the pic, please look at it. I am trying to get contacts from my phone and display the image, contact name, and phone number in my listview(with customview). I am able to retrieve and display them in the listview, but the customview is spanning the entire height of the listview, instead of taking the 60dp, that the layout should take (CustomView - ListView Item ::: android:layout_height="60dp" ).

Comment: Oh, sorry I see what you're asking now. Nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter's getView method, when you inflate the listview item, don't pass null in as the parent view as you are doing here:

```
convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview_addcontact_item, null);
```

Instead, pass the supplied parent view and false to the alternate overloaded inflate method:

```
convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview_addcontact_item, parent, false);
```

If you don't pass the parent in, the layout_height value that you set in your xml layout file will not be honored.